# Intersection of vectors to form a tetrahedron

Tags: vectors

Suppose we have three unit vectors, namely $a,b,$ and $c,$ such that the angle between any of them is the acute angle $\theta.$ However, these vectors generate a tetrahedron with volume $\frac{1}{\sqrt{360}}.$ Find $$3\cos^2\theta - 2\cos^3\theta.$$

---

I've got little to no idea on how to start this problem due to the fact that it's a new concept to me. Can someone give me an overview of the basics and then a sketch of the problem for me to work on?

Comment: Seems like some condition is missing here. Unless we can assume something about the magnitude of $a,b,c$, it is impossible to say anything about $\theta$. Imagine if you could "grow" $a,b,c$ in magnitude - you could maintain the same volume by decreasing $\theta$ - making the tetrahedron more "pointy". Are $a,b,c$ maybe assumed to be *unit* vectors (of magnitude $1$)?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry. It was the unit vectors, I'll edit that in.

Comment: The volume of the tetrahedron is $\frac16a\cdot(b\times c)$. That might help....

Comment: So we have that $\frac{a}{6} \cdot bc = \frac{1}{\sqrt{360}}.$ That's interesting, but how would that help find $\theta$?

Comment: Don't believe the concept is so new. The easiest way to start (for me, I am fond of vectors approach, but I don't see how to use it here) is sketch the tetrahedron $SABC$ with $SA=SB=SC=1$ and the demanded angles equal ($\triangle ABC$ will be equilateral), then find its volume the regular way, like $\frac13\,h_S\,\operatorname{Area}(\triangle ABC)$ in terms of $\theta$ and equate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following image

[image]

where the three angles in $V$ are $\theta$, develope the image in a plane, obtaining

[image]

Now we can observe that
\begin{align}
&\overline{AV}=\overline{BV}=\overline{CV}=1\\
&\overline{AB}=\overline{BC}=\overline{CA}=2\sin(\theta/2)\\
&\overline{HV}=\overline{KV}=\overline{LV}=\cos(\theta/2)\\
&\overline{AH}=\overline{BK}=\overline{CL}=\sqrt{3}\sin(\theta/2)\\
&\overline{H\Omega}=\overline{K\Omega}=\overline{L\Omega}=(\sqrt{3}/3)\sin(\theta/2)\\
\end{align}
then the height of the tetrahedron is
$$
h=\overline{V\Omega}=\sqrt{\overline{HV}^2-\overline{H\Omega}^2}=\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta/2)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^2(\theta/2)},
$$
while the base area is
$$
A_b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\overline{AB}^2=\sqrt{3}\sin^2(\theta/2).
$$
Finally, the volume is
$$
\mathscr{V}=\frac{1}{3}A_bh=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\sin^2(\theta/2)\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta/2)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^2(\theta/2)}.
$$
Now observe that
\begin{align}
\mathscr{V}^2&=\frac{1}{3}\sin^4(\theta/2)\left(\cos^2(\theta/2)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^2(\theta/2)\right)=\\
&=\frac{1}{36}(1+2\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)^2=\\
&=\frac{1}{36}(1-3\cos^2\theta+2\cos^3\theta).
\end{align}
Now, from
$$
\mathscr{V}^2=\frac{1}{36}(1-3\cos^2\theta+2\cos^3\theta)=\frac{1}{360}
$$
we find
$$
3\cos^2\theta-2\cos^3\theta=\frac{9}{10}.
$$